# navigation background transparency issues

Tags: html, css, blogger

My problem im having is my drop down menu background is some how transparent and im able to see the text on the page behind the menu. Also i am using blogger if that makes any difference.

Here is my problem in this image

[image]

Here is my code here"

```
<div style="text-align: left;">

<style>


#homelink {
background-image: url(http://i946.photobucket.com/albums/ad301/campbellmichelle41109/sims3_logo_ver931034_zpsmnyi2tcj.png);
background-repeat:  no-repeat;

background-color: transparent;
display: block;
width: 126px;
height: 140px;
}




#homelink {
position: relative;
padding: 0;
margin: -97px;
}



#mbt-menu, #mbt-me
nu ul {
margin: -15px;
padding: 12px;
list-style: none;
}

#mbt-menu ul {
   border: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
#mbt-menu {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
javascript:void(0)
background-image: url("http://i946.photobucket.com/albums/ad301/campbellmichelle41109/navbg1.1_zps86kuvvkj.png") repeat-x;

-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;

}
#mbt-menu:before,
#mbt-menu:after {
content: "";
display: table;
}
#mbt-menu:after {
clear: both;
}
#mbt-menu {
zoom:1;
}
#mbt-menu li {
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid #328ad4;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #469ee8;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #469ee8;
box-shadow: 0px 0 0 #469ee8;
position: relative;
}
#mbt-menu a {
float: left;
padding: 10px 25px;
color: #ffffff;
text-transform: uppercase;
font: bold 13px 'Trebuchet MS',Arial, sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 0px 0 #000;
}

#mbt-menu li ul a{
color: #000000;
}

#mbt-menu li ul a:hover{
color: #057BBA;
}

#mbt-menu li:hover > a {
color: #0;
}
*html #mbt-menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
color: #000000;
}
#mbt-menu ul li {
border-style: solid;
border-color: #EBEBEB;
}


#mbt-menu ul {
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
_margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
opaciaty: 0;
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 55px;
left: 15px;
z-index: 9999;
background: #ffffff;

-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#mbt-menu li:hover > ul {
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
margin: 0;
}
#mbt-menu ul ul {
top: 0;
left: 150px;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
_margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/


}
#mbt-menu ul li {

float: none;
display: block;
border: 0;
_line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/
border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
}
#mbt-menu ul li:last-child {
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
#mbt-menu ul a {
padding: 7px;
width: 130px;
_height: 9px; /*IE6 only*/
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
float: none;
text-transform: none;
}


#mbt-menu ul a{
font-size: 12px;
}

#mbt-menu ul a:hover {
background-color: #ffffff;
}
#mbt-menu ul li:first-child > a {
-moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#mbt-menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
left: -6px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -6px;
border-left: 0;
border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
border-top: 6px solid transparent;
border-right: 6px solid #3b3b3b;
}
#mbt-menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
border-bottom-color: #04acec;
}
#mbt-menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
border-right-color: #0299d3;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
#mbt-menu ul li:last-child > a {
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

/* non links */

#mbt-menu ul {
color: #000000;
font-size: 12px;
}

#mbt-menu li ul:hover {
color: #057BBA;
}

#mbt-menu ul {
pading: 7px;
width: 130px;
height: 34px;
_height: 9px;
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
float: none;
text-transform: none;
}

#mbt-menu {
font: bold 13px 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 0px 0 #000;
}

</style>

<div align=center>

<ul id="mbt-menu"> 
<li><a id=homelink href="http://thesims3addictresource.blogspot.com/"></a></li> 



<li> 
<a href="#">Simology</a> 
<ul> 
                 <li>Sims

        <ul>
                <li><a href="">Faries</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Ghosts</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Plant Sims</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Witches</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Werewolves</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Vampires</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Zombies</a>

        </ul>

</li>

<li><a href="http://thesims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/needs.html">Needs</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://thesims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/skills.html">Skills</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://thesims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/traits.html">Traits</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://thesims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/moodlets.html">Moodlets</a></li> 

             <li><a href="">Life & Death</a>

             <ul>  
               <li><a href="http://thesims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/death.html">Death</a></li> 
               <li><a href="http://thesims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/ghosts.html">Ghosts</a></li>
             </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="http://thesims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/lifetime-wishes.html">Lifetime Wishes</a></li>
<li><a href="http://thesims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/lifetime-rewards.html">Life Time Rewards</a></li>




</ul> 
</li> 




<li> 
    <a href="#">Expansion Guide</a> 

        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">Ambitions</a> 

                <ul>
                <li><a href="">New Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="">New Lifetime Rewards</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Celebrities</a></li>
                </ul>

            <li><a href="#">Generations</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Pets</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Late Night</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Supernatural</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">World Adventures</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">University Life</a></li>
                </li>
        </ul> 
</li> 


<li> 
<a href="#">Towns</a> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">Sunset Valley</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Monte Vista</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Hidden Springs</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Dragon Valley</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Roaring Heights</a></li> 
</ul> 
</li> 

<li>
<a href="#">Free Downloads</a>


           <ul>
         <li><a href="http://thesims3addictresource.blogspot.com/p/custom-sims.html"> Custom Sims </a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sliders</a></li>
         </ul>
 </li>


<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 

</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide link to your blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add/Update the following entries in your css code.

```
#mbt-menu ul li, #mbt-menu>li li a {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Also remove the following **width** property. its causing problem due to fixed width of `ul` element

```
#mbt-menu ul a{
    /*Other styles*/
    width:130px;
    /*Other styles*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add a `background-color` property for the following ID.

```
#mbt-menu {
    font: bold 13px 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0px 0 #000;
    background-color: /*your color code*/;
}
```

Comment: I have checked your code and its working fine for me. You have already add background color for dropdown menu #mbt-menu ul {background: #ffffff;}. If its not working please add !important after color like "background:#fff !important;}

Comment: Im still having the problem here look at it on my site here http://thesims3addictresource.blogspot.com/

Comment: Please update the following styles on `#mbt-menu ul li`. and there are a problem on the hover status on each menu item. please update the `#mbt-menu ul a`  as well. below are the updated styles,
`#mbt-menu ul li {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EBEBEB;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}

#mbt-menu ul a {
    padding: 7px;
    width: 113px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}`